# Hydra - accessing parent of parent directory

Tags: python, fb-hydra

is it possible to have a 2-degree sibling file as a default configuration?

Files hierarchy:

```
dir_1
├── dir_1_1
│   └── dir_1_1_1
│       └── conf.yaml
└── dir_1_2
    └── dir_1_2_1
        └── dataset_paths_1.yaml
```

I want to have dataset_path configurations as a default configurations in conf.yaml.

What I tried:

**conf.yaml:**

```
defaults:
  - /../../dir_1_2/dir_1_2_1@dataset_paths: dataset_paths_1
  - _self_
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access configs which are not in your subtree in an absolute addressing.
Note that I am assuming that `dir_1` is a root in your config search path.

```yaml
defaults:
  - /dir_1_2/dir_1_2_1@dataset_paths: dataset_paths_1
  - _self_
```

See [The Defaults List](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/).

Comment: Is it possible from dir_1_1_1?

Comment: Quoting from the doc: "The path is relative to the containing config. It can be made absolute by prefixing it with a /"